# Block means of a matrix with fixed interval R

Tags: r, matrix

I'm quite new to R and I have not found a solution for my problem despite intensive searching. What I need to do is to find the block means for the columns of for example, a 200x10 matrix for intervals of 10 rows. 
In other words, I would like to have the colum means for row 1:10, 11:20, and so in so that in the end I will have a 20x10 matrix of averages.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll work with a `matrix` object or a `data.frame`?

Comment: It's a data.frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you have evenly "blocked" data, here is a solution with `rowsum`,

```
rowsum(myMat, rep(1:20, each=10)) / 10
```

Here, `rep(1:20, each=10)` provides the grouping variable, with the integers 1 through 20 repeated 10 times each, (like 1 1 1 1 1 ... 2 2 2 2 ... 20 20 20 20).

For the data below, this returns

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
1  10.4 11.5 11.1  8.4  9.3 11.5 12.1 10.8  8.6   7.9
2   9.4 12.5 12.4 10.6 10.3 11.8 11.2  8.8  9.0  12.5
3   8.9  8.1  9.0 12.5  7.4 10.3 11.5 13.1 12.2   9.8
4  10.2 11.7 13.2 12.4 12.5 11.0 10.2  8.9 11.3   9.5
         ...
18 10.6 11.1 10.5 10.6 12.3  7.9 12.2  7.6 12.3  14.9
19 10.5  8.0 10.5  8.5 10.5 12.8 12.4 12.0 10.9   9.0
20 15.3 11.3 11.8 11.5 10.7  8.8 11.1  9.8 10.6  11.8
```

It will work on data.frames as well.

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
myMat <- matrix(sample(1:20, 2000, replace=TRUE), 200)
rowsum(myMat, rep(1:20, each=10)) / 10
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not understanding where 1:20 in rep is coming from. Could you please explain?

Comment: Sure thing. I added an additional comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot, also for the extra explanation.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `split` and `colMeans`.  We `split` the dataset by a grouping vector with `gl`, then get the column means of the `list` elements (`colMeans`) and transpose the output

```
t(sapply(split(as.data.frame(myMat),
       as.numeric(gl(nrow(myMat), 10, nrow(myMat)))), colMeans))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
myMat <- matrix(rnorm(200*10),nrow=200)
```

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi  I think it may create some problems and need `drop=TRUE`

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways to solve this, but this is one. Basically you create an additional vector to  define the groupings, and then `aggregate` on that.

```
df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(100), b=rnorm(100))
res <- aggregate(df, by=list(rep(1:10,each=10)), mean)
```